# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'photo' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, graphql, graphql-js

```
{
  "data": {
    "photo": {
      "id": "3",
      "categoryId": 1,
      "src": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1513360371669-4adf3dd7dff8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60",
      "likes": 7,
      "userId": "1",
      "liked": false
    }
  }
}
```

The query is working correctly.

```
const query = gql`
  query getSinglePhoto($id: ID!) {
    photo(id: $id) {
      id
      categoryId
      src
      likes
      userId
      liked
    }
  }
`;
```

I would like get the object named photo
But I am not sure cuz the console show undefined.
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'photo' of undefined**

```
    "photo": {
      "id": "3",
      "categoryId": 1,
      "src": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1513360371669-4adf3dd7dff8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60",
      "likes": 7,
      "userId": "1",
      "liked": false
    }
```

Here is the problem. In the part const {photo = {}} = data. I found to get the object named photo, but I was unlucky.

```
export const PhotoCardWithQuery = ({ id }) => (
  <Query query={query} variables={{ id }}>
    {({ loading, error, data }) => {
      const { photo = {} } = data;
      console.log(photo);
      return <PhotoCard />;
    }}
  </Query>
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time your component renders, loading will be true and data will be undefined, as the data has not loaded.

You need to add a check to make sure that loading is false and data is populated before trying to extract photo from it.

```
<Query query={query} variables={{ id }}>
{({ loading, error, data }) => {
  if (loading || !data) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  const { photo = {} } = data;
  console.log(photo);
  return <PhotoCard />;
}}
```